# Collapsing rows in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to collapse rows in a dataframe that contains a column of ID data and a number of columns that each hold a different string. It looks like groupby is the solution, but it seems to be slanted towards performing some numeric function on the group - I just want to keep the text. Here's what I've got...

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
index    ID     apples    pears    oranges
0        101                       oranges
1        134    apples
2        576              pears
3        837    apples
4        576                       oranges
5        134              pears
```

The columns are clean: so the apples column will only ever have the text "apples" in it, or it will be blank".

Where there are multiple entries under the same ID (in this example, on IDs 134 & 576), I want to collapse the rows together to get this:

```
index    ID     apples    pears    oranges
0        101                       oranges
1        134    apples    pears
2        576              pears    oranges
3        837    apples
```

I could do this by iterating over the rows, but it seems like a non-pandas solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregation `''.join`, `sum` or `max`:

```
#if blank values are NaN first replace to ''
df = df.fillna('')

df = df.groupby('ID').agg(''.join)
print (df)
     apples  pears  oranges
ID                         
101                 oranges
134  apples  pears         
576          pears  oranges
837  apples
```

Also works:

```
df = df.fillna('')
df = df.groupby('ID').sum()
#alternatively max
#df = df.groupby('ID').max()
print (df)
     apples  pears  oranges
ID                         
101                 oranges
134  apples  pears         
576          pears  oranges
837  apples
```

Also if need remove duplicates per group and per column add [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))
```

Comment: The first suggestion works perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Any chance that you could describe what's going on in the line: `df = df.groupby('ID').agg(''.join)` ?

Comment: A warning, and avery late response to user4896331 and jezrael. `.agg(''.join)` worked great for me (More on the basic concept is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) but pandas just dropped columns that had blanks when I used `.agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))`. I had to use `.astype(str)` and `.replace(to_replace=[None],value='')` to end up with all the data that I had started with. Also worth noting in my case, all data could be strings.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming blanks are `''`

***option 1***
*`pivot_table`*

```
df.pivot_table(['apples', 'pears', 'oranges'], 'ID', aggfunc=''.join)
```

***option 2***
*`sort` and take last row as `''` will be sorted first*

```
def f(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, 0)[[-1]], [df.name], df.columns)

df.set_index(
    'ID', append=True
).groupby(level='ID', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

---

*Both yield*

```
     apples  oranges  pears
ID                         
101          oranges       
134  apples           pears
576          oranges  pears
837  apples
```