# De-duplicating and transposing columns data in pandas & python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have an data frame that looks like this

```
Column1-Column2
a      - 12
b      - t1
c      - t3
d      - 798
a      - 87
b      - g1
a      - 478
c      - f1
d      - 906
```

I would like to get a data frame that is like this:

```
Columns: 
a, b, c, d
Rows:
12, t1, t3, 798
87, g1, -, -
478, -, f1, 906
```

Basically, I would like to de-dup columns and populate the associated row data.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your rows always have 'a' column value, you can do this like this:

```
#standard imports
import pandas as pd

initial = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Column1' : [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            'a',
            'b',
            'a',
            'c',
            'd'
        ],
        'Column2':[
            '12',
            't1',
            't3',
            '798',
            '87',
            'g1',
            '478',
            'f1',
            '906'
        ]
    }
)

pivoted = initial.pivot(columns='Column1', values='Column2')

target = pivoted.groupby(pivoted.apply(lambda x: 1 if x[0]!=None else 0, axis=1).cumsum())[pivoted.columns].agg(lambda x: ''.join([el for el in x if el!=None]))
```

If you can have missing 'a' values, then it gets trickier. That's why it's so important to give representative examples in your questions.

EDIT:

Iterative approach, if you can have non-existing 'a' values in a row:

```
#use `initial` dataframe from answer above
target = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
newrow = dict()
for index, row in initial.iterrows():
    if row['Column1'] in newrow:
        target=target.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
        newrow=dict()
    newrow[row['Column1']]=row['Column2']

target=target.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Also, this is kind of a duplicate of these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319649/collapsing-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-if-all-rows-have-only-one-value-in-their-c
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514019/collapsing-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I did give an example. I do have null values in many as represented by the "-"

Comment: All your 'a' values are not null, that's why I made a simplifying assumption. Also, your dataset has to be manually retyped to reproduce the case, because it's not given as a list or dictionary assignment, just a raw result. Look at my code, you can copy-paste it to reproduce my results. That's how the question should be formulated. In any case - did my answer work for you?

Comment: I've edited the answer to accomodate for not-existing 'a' values. Not as clean as the initial solution, but more general.

Comment: Thanks so much - I will try it out.

Comment: Thanks this works great -- just 1 more ask - is there a way to denote columns automatically?   for example here you have used                    
       target = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])                                                  i have a huge column list: Column 1 is a massive list. I want to pick only the unique ones and iterate. I can create a list with unique column names  using set() or unique(). But how do i pass that to the columns?

Comment: target = pd.DataFrame(columns=initial['Column1'].unique()) ?