# Pandas: collapse rows with same column ID and concatenate multiple columns into 1

Tags: python, pandas

Without iterating over the dataframe, is it possible using pandas methods to "collapse" from this

```
index    ID     fruits    qty
0        101    oranges   1
1        134    apples    2
2        576    pears     3
3        837    apples    1
4        576    oranges   2
5        134    pears     3
```

to this (and generate a new `description` column in the process that sort of summarizes the info into a single string):

```
index    ID     description
0        101    101: orange(1)
1        134    134: apples(2) pears(3)
2        576    576: pears(3) oranges(2)
3        837    837: apples(1)
```

Note that this is a spin on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514019/collapsing-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join columns `fruits` with `qty`, then aggregate `join` and last add `ID` converted to strings:

```
df['description'] = df['fruits'] + '(' + df['qty'].astype(str) + ')'

df = df.groupby('ID')['description'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
df['description'] = df['ID'].astype(str)  + ': ' + df['description'] 
print (df)
    ID               description
0  101           101: oranges(1)
1  134   134: apples(2) pears(3)
2  576  576: pears(3) oranges(2)
3  837            837: apples(1)
```

Another idea with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    d = x['fruits'] + '(' + x['qty'].astype(str) + ')'
    return x.name.astype(str)  + ': ' + ' '.join(d)

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(f).reset_index(name='description')

print (df)
    ID               description
0  101           101: oranges(1)
1  134   134: apples(2) pears(3)
2  576  576: pears(3) oranges(2)
3  837            837: apples(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas there is the apply function.
Using this function you can apply lambda functions to rows, columns, or even whole dataframes.

Here is the documentation link to the function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html